# OpenCV, random segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

I am having a odd segmentation fault and I'm at wits end, right as I am about to start using the program.

```
cout << type2str(fg.type()) << endl; // "8UC4"
if (type2str(fg.type()) == "8UC4"){
  //fg is a Mat loaded from fg = imread(path);
  fg_channels = fg.at<Vec4b>(v_index, h_index); //The seg fault happens here 100% deterministically
}
else if (type2str(fg.type()) == "8UC3")
{
  temp = fg.at<Vec3b>(v_index,h_index);
  fg_channels = Vec4b(temp.val[0], temp.val[1], temp.val[2], 255);
}
```

How can I get more information from C++ about the segmentation fault?  I'm losing my mind, this is happening well within the bounds of the image that I have written into fg.

This doesn't happen until about halfway through the fg, both rows and columns get iterated through quite a number of times.  Any ideas on how I can trouble shoot this problem?  And does segmentation fault tell me something useful about the problem I'm having?  I normally think of index out of bounds when i get segfault, but I don't think that makes sense here.

Comment: Sanitizer/Valgrind?

Comment: @Evg Thanks for the suggestion, ill check it out and see if it can help me

Comment: What are the values of v_index, h_index and what's the size of fg (rows and cols)?

Comment: it is `at<something>(row, col)` -- you seem to have it in reverse

Comment: Maybe debug anch check the values of `Vec4b`, `v_index` and `h_index`... And see if you didn't inverse them? ;)

Comment: Get image size before calling `at()`, to make sure you have the image you spect

Comment: I read h/v_index as **horizontal/vertical** index, so that should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what image you are reading, but this example worked fine:

```
cv::Mat fg = cv::imread("camera.png", CV_8UC4);
cv::cvtColor(fg, fg, CV_BGR2BGRA);
int v_index = 100000;
int h_index = 1000000;
if (fg.cols < v_index) v_index = fg.cols-1;
if (fg.rows < h_index) h_index = fg.rows-1;
std::cout << type2str(fg.type()) << std::endl; // "8UC4"
if (type2str(fg.type()) == "8UC4") {
  //fg is a Mat loaded from fg = imread(path);
  cv::Vec4b fg_channels = fg.at<cv::Vec4b>(v_index, h_index); //The seg fault happens here 100% deterministically
  std::cout << fg_channels << std::endl;
}
else if (type2str(fg.type()) == "8UC3")
{
  cv::Vec3b temp = fg.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0);
  cv::Vec4b fg_channels = cv::Vec4b(temp.val[0], temp.val[1], temp.val[2], 255);
}
```

The output from `std::cout << fg_channels << std::endl;` gives [24, 83, 74, 255]

The output from `std::cout << type2str(fg.type()) << std::endl; // "8UC4"` gives 8UC4, so you example seems to work.

If you do something like:

```
if (fg.cols < v_index) v_index = fg.cols * fg.cols;
if (fg.rows < h_index) h_index = fg.rows * fg.rows;
```

Then you will get an OpenCV Error: `Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor`  Because you are outside the available indexes of the image on the line you mentioned.

Comment: mind the (undisclosed!) meaning of `h_index` and `v_index`. we don't know what they mean, so you can't reliably give code that compares them to number of rows and columns.

Comment: ok. Good to know for next time when answering questions. Also the question mentions iterations, but no attempt to show iterations in the question.  I try my best to answer a question as presented by the presenter.